# Column Offset Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with the names in each column;
Example

Column A=Name-01, Column B=Name-02, Column C=Name-03 etc

I want to copy the name of each column to another spreadsheet to rows
Example

```
   A1=SheetName Column A=Name-01
   A2=SheetName Column B=Name-02
   A3=SheetName Column C=Name-03
```

Comment: so in the second sheet A1 you want the first sheet A1 and in the second sheet A2 you want first sheet B1 and so forth?

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1,ROW(1:1))
```

Now as you drag it down column A it will refer to the next cell in the first row of the other sheet.